# How can I manually insert the length of interword space and inter sentence space?

Tags: fontspec, punctuation

By `\defaultfontfeatures{PunctuationSpace=1.5}` I set the space between sentences (to 1.5 * interword space, if I understand it). How can I manually insert this very space, if there is no sentence ending with a punctuation mark? This happens e.g. with `\textquote[p.\,2}{This is a special quote.}`? In the text it ends with "(p.2)", followed by interword space, whereas I want a space as between sentences.

I need a length like `\PunctuationSpace`, to be used after quotations etc. (`\hspace{1\PunctuationSpace}`).

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,UKenglish,french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=german,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily]{PunctuationSpace=1.5,%
                                             Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\nonfrenchspacing
blablablablablabla \textquote[S.\,2]{This is a very special sentence, quoted from \textit{Special Sentences}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question would be a lot clearer if you provided an example document.  are you using `\xspace` here as a random example command name or reference to the command of that name defined by the `\xspace` package (which doesn't seem  relevant as far as I understood your question)  and is `\hlength`  a typo for `\hspace` ?  You don't show a definition for `\textquote` but it could copy the spacefactor past the inserted `(p 2)` and so giv ean end of sentence space if the main argument ends with `.`

Comment: Before I re-write it: `\xspace` is from `\usepackage{xspace}`, `\hlength` should be `\hspace`, and `\textquote` is from `\usepackage{csquotes}`.

Comment: hmm I wrote the xspace package and I can't guess how you would use it in any way related to this question:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is saved in `\fontdimen7\font`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}

Some nonsense words
\textquote[p.\,2]{This is a special quote.}
Some nonsense.

Some nonsense words
\textquote[p.\,2]{This is a special quote.}\hspace{\fontdimen7\font}
Some nonsense.

\end{document}
```